# React app with Rocket backend giving ECONNREFUSED when using proxy

Tags: reactjs, rust-rocket

I'm trying to make a web app using rocket for the backend and react for the frontend. However, when I try to make a proxy I keep getting `rayk@pop-os:~/repos/homrs/frontend$ curl http://localhost:3000/api Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000 (ECONNREFUSED).`

The things I've currently tried are adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"` to my package.json in the application and I've always tried configuring the proxy manually as suggested here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually.

Here is the backend code I'm using to test:

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/api", routes![index]).launch();
}
```

Here is the `setupProxy.js` I attempted to use

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:8000',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

I also have attempted to use `http://localhost:8000` and `http://localhost:8000/`. I have also tried changing the rocket port from 8000 to 3001 and that also did not work.

Edit: Here is a link to the github repo: https://github.com/GimpFlamingo/homrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people here: https://github.com/plouc/mozaik/issues/118 were having a similar issue.

I was able to reproduce your issue and found adding `address = "127.0.0.1"` to Rocket.toml and then setting "proxy" to "http://127.0.0.1:8080" fixed it for me!